# PHP 7.1 json_decode() undefined

Tags: php, json, ubuntu

i'm try to use composer.But return `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function Composer\Console\json_decode() in /usr/share/php/Composer/Console/Application.php:145` 
I'm using ubuntu 16.04. and php 7.1.

```
`apt-get install php7.1-json` -> installed
```

if i execute php -m command no Json in return list . /etc/php/7.1/mods-available/ folder have not anyone .ini file.And i added extension=json.so to php.ini file but did not work

**EDIT**

etc/php tree

```
├── 7.0
│   └── apache2
│       └── conf.d
└── 7.1
    ├── apache2
    │   └── php.ini
    └── mods-available
```

Comment: Strange, it  seems as though it's trying to find json_decode() within the Composer namespace where really it should be looking in the base namespace. Eg \json_decode() instead of simply json_decode()

Comment: You probably have conflicting php versions. Do `php -v` to check what the default one is

Comment: Composer doesn't have an Application.php is that your own code?

Comment: php -v return php version 7.0.21 .But if i look etc/php/7.0 folder is empty than ect/php/7.1 (so i mean php.ini and mods-available folder in 7.1)I think so maybe you are right.How do I get in front of this stranger? @apokryfos

Comment: Do `which php` and delete the file that it mentions. Find the folder of the correct PHP file and do `cp <php path>/bin/php /usr/bin/php` or something like that. You should have done an `apt-get purge php-7.0 before installing PHP-7.1 though to be safe